# Angular 2+ filling an html table with ngFor when data is get from api

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm quite new to Angular so although I'm trying to accomplish something I guess it's not difficult I'm stuck and need your help.

What I need to do is to fill an html table with clients data on button click and after data is received from an api call.

I'm being able to display "fixed" data with ngFor if I define it as a public property of the TypeScript class as seen with clientsData1 (I leave it as an example), but cannot bind ngFor to variable containing json result (clientsData) changes.

In short, what I'm trying to do is when I click button I launch getItems method and as soon as getItems has a result I need to update the table.

This is my TypeScript class:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public clientsData : string;
  private clientsUrl : string = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5808862710000087232b75ac';
  public clientsData1 : any = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 5}];
  constructor (private http: Http) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    let btnGetClients = document.getElementById("btnGetClients");
    btnGetClients.addEventListener("click", (e:Event) => this.getItems()
        .subscribe(
          ipdata => this.clientsData = ipdata.clientsJson
        ));
  }  
  getItems(): Observable<IPData> {    
        return this.http.get(this.clientsUrl)
                        .map(this.extractData);
  }
  extractData(res: Response) {
    return res.json();
  }
}
class IPData {
  public clientsJson : string;
}
```

And this is the html template:

```
<h1>Insurance App</h1>
<hr />
<button id="btnGetClients">Get Clients</button>
<br/><br/>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let client of clientsData">
        <tr>
            <td>{{client.id}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In case if you haven't noted you are storing data in clientsData and iterating over clientsData1

Comment: Yes Birju, and I've left it that way on purpose as an example of a way I'm being able to update DOM with data. Anyway I'll edit it so no one else gets confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly this is bad practice to use any DOM manipulation in your TS files. You can add click event handler like this

```
<button (click)='getItemsSubscription()'>Get Clients</button>
```

and to iterate trough array that are not present from the moment when component are created you need to use ngFor like this

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let client of clientsData">
        <tr>
            <td>{{client?.id}}</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody
```

with a quote mark on client. Quote mark means that you will get your data rendered when you will have it on you component lexical environment, or won't render it at all.

And one more thing if you want to call data with a button click. When you calling to a function you are not subscribing to it, so you need to wrap it up and do something like this

```
  getItemsSubscription() {
       this.getItems().subscribe(
              ipdata => this.clientsData = ipdata.clientsJson
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response Kraken. I did modifications on code to match your suggestion but when I click the button nothing really happens.

Comment: Yes for sure i didn't notice that you got `public clientsData : string;` change type to any

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts guys. I know I'm quite close thanks to your help but yet no luck.
If I "manually" create the variable clientsData in getItems() this way: this.clientsData = [{'id': 2}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 6}]; in the html I can see dom updated with data but api returns json in a slightly different way so maybe this is the problem?
This is the api url: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5808862710000087232b75ac

Comment: Thank you very much Kraken, your new comment is ok but I'm sure the problem now is with the json format the api is returning, is not [{},{},...] but {"clients": [{}, {}, ...]} so maybe I need to extract the clients node or maybe instead of writting {{client?.id}} I should write something slightly different.

Comment: so ipdata.clients or ipdata.clientsJson.clients, you need an array, you can;t iterate though object via ngFor

Comment: Ok @Kraken, I've finally done it and your help was the key because you pointed me in the right direction from the beginning.
In my case class IPData is useless (have taken it from another example) so the final key was remove IPData class, return Observable<string> in getItems and return res.json().clients in extractData.
I'll mark your answer as correct and thanks for your valuable help.